# (Mockito + Kotlin) eq() and any() in Android Test returns null

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, mockito, android-testing

Things are going fine in test package, however, they are going wayward in androidTest package.

Things I have already tried:

Instead of `Mockito.any()` I have already tried following snippet

```
fun <T> any(): T {
    Mockito.any<T>()
    return uninitialized()
}
private fun <T> uninitialized(): T = null as T
```

This also returns null in case of androidTest, however it runs fine in test package

I have also tried [nhaarman's mockito-kotlin](https://github.com/nhaarman/mockito-kotlin) that didn't help either

Any help will be highly appreciated.